# Microsoft Access How to retrieve current form ID to print

Tags: ms-access, printing, report, ms-access-2010

I am trying to print a report called Carton Labels, and I want to print a specific record that the user just created. Every time I try using Me.cartonNo which is a actual field on the current form the user is on. He gets prompted for input. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

EDIT:

```
Dim strDocName As String
Dim strFilter As String

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

strDocName = "Carton Labels"
strFilter = "[cartonNo] = Forms![frm_addFinishedGoodsInventory]![cartonNo]"

DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName, acViewPreview, strFilter
```

my print button doesn't work, it acts as if nothing was stored in the strFilter, but if I create Dim intFilter As Integer and store it into a integer, I can clearly see the cartonNo if I set a break point, yet I dont in the strFilter.

Comment: I would avoid macros, unless you need to work on-line. They are difficult to control.

Comment: @Fionnuala I added my new VBA Code, since you recommended to stay away from macro's

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the carton number before you pass it to OpenReport. By placing the Forms! reference outside the quotation marks like this:

```
strFilter = "[cartonNo] = " & Forms![frm_addFinishedGoodsInventory]![cartonNo]
```

you are creating the string `[cartonNo] = 6` and then passing that to the report. If the field were a text field  (or date), you'd need to include quotes (or #s) around the value.

Comment: The strFilter works perfectly, I can see the actual number getting stored into it. But my filter isn't getting applied to my OpenReport.

Comment: You're positive that the table or query that's driving the report has a field called cartonNo?  Not the report itself, but the data source for the report.  And that the field cartonNo is expecting a number and not text?

Comment: @JohnnyBones my cartonNo field is expecting a string not a number.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I tried wrapping my entire strFilter = in Quotes " " as well.

Comment: Make sure that the report is **closed** before running the DoCmd.OpenReport. If it is already open, the filter will not be applied. This happens often in development, when you are playing with the report and the code that opens it at the same time. You could add `If Application.CurrentProject.AllReports(strDocName).IsLoaded = True Then DoCmd.Close acReport, strDocName, docmd.Close acReport,,acSavePrompt`